# Two status bar in the app when application comes in foreground from background and UI freezes in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, statusbar, uiactivityindicatorview

I am working on an iOS app in which I have to do `numerous calculations in the loop which is running say 5000 times on the main thread`. So its taking a little bit time before loading the UI and activity indicator is loading till then.If the app goes background and comes back to foreground the UI **freezes** for the time till the app completes the loop operation.

One specific thing that I found is that I am getting **two status bar** in the app which is overlapping each other.you can see `time and battery percentage` value overlapping each other (Refer Screen Shot below).This only happens when app goes to background and comes back to foreground `freezing my Activity Indicator`. Even though if I want to replace the activity with a new one or stop and start it again still there is no response and the UI is freezes unless the loop completes its iteration and sometimes leading to **app crash** as well.

If app calculation is completed (normal case) and then if app goes to back ground and comes back then every thing works smoothly.

[image]

Please suggest me whats going wrong with my app.

Comment: Why don't you do calculating operations on background thread and stop the activity indicator on completion of background tasks.

Comment: read this for better understanding of background thread https://www.objc.io/issues/2-concurrency/common-background-practices/

Comment: @MrWaqasAhmed.. Thanks I will read that article. One more concern I have is the status bar overlap in my app when app comes in foreground from back ground.  What could be the reason behind it?

Comment: You held the main thread hostage too long.